# Prove that $\mu\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; \frac{1}{x}>\alpha\right\}\right)\ge\frac{1}{|\alpha|}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

We consider the function
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} \;\; \mathrm{if} \;\; x \ne 0\\
0 \;\; \mathrm{if} \;\; x =0
\end{cases}$$

> $\forall\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$\mu\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; f(x)>\alpha\right\}\right)\ge\frac{1}{|\alpha|}$$

Could someone please explain this to me?
What is used?

Comment: What is $\mu$? And why you introduce $f$? Can you please provide some context?

Comment: Sorry, I correct.

Comment: Draw a little picture of $f$, draw a horizontal line at various $\alpha$ and figure out what the measure it.

Comment: @copper.hatI tried the integral of $1/x$, but this integral diverges!

Comment: Why would you possibly need an integral? You can compute the measure explicitly for $\alpha \le 0$ and $\alpha >0$.

Comment: It is not clear what $f$ has to do with the question, it is just noise.

Comment: yes! I resolved!

Comment: Well for $a>0$, you can see that $$\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; \frac{1}{x}>\alpha\right\} = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;0<x<1/a\right\}$$
and so $μ\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;|\; \frac{1}{x}>\alpha\right\}\right)=\frac1a$.

For $a\leq 0$, notice that the set for which the measure you want to find, contains the subset $(0,+\infty)$, which has infinite measure, and so the same holds for the original set, by the monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure.

Putting these together, you can conclude the inequality you want.